# Android: How to use SetTag() from random drawable?

Tags: java, android, random

I'm still newbie, so I hope I could get some help here.
So here I have two pictures/drawable to be randomized.
I could do the randomized for picture, but I want to play match sound depend on what picture appears.

this is how I do the randomization :

```
apple.setBackgroundResource(imgDeck[random.nextInt(imgDeck.length)]);
apple.setTag(R.drawable.image_a);
```

problem: I want to change parameter of the setTag to be something like `R.drawable.*` from the randomized I did before (in setbcakground resource).

Here is the complete code from `fragment_a.java`.

```
public class fragment_a extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton a, apple;
MediaPlayer sound;

// Random object
private final static Random random = new Random();

// Tampung Image
private final static int[] imgDeck = new int[] { 
    R.drawable.image_a,
    R.drawable.image_b };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    a = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_a);
    a.setOnClickListener(fragment_a.this);

    apple = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_apple);
    apple.setOnClickListener(fragment_a.this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (view == getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton_a)) {

        apple.setBackgroundResource(imgDeck[random.nextInt(imgDeck.length)]);
        apple.setTag(R.drawable.image_a);

        a.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        apple.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

        if (apple.getTag().equals(R.drawable.image_a)) {

            sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    R.raw.sound_apple);
            sound.setVolume(5, 5);
            sound.start();
        } else if (apple.getTag().equals(R.drawable.image_b)) {
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    R.raw.sound_banana);
            sound.setVolume(5, 5);
            sound.start();
        }

    } else if (view == getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton_apple)) {

        a.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        apple.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                R.raw.sound_a);
        sound.setVolume(5, 5);
        sound.start();
    } else {
        a.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        apple.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                R.raw.sound_apple);
        sound.setVolume(5, 5);
        sound.start();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Try it ...put your Drawable(Images) at a ArrayList and access it using Index number